# Setting the right space for /usr/local

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, software-installation, matlab

One month ago I dual booted and gave my root partition around 25GB following guidelines such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164179/please-recommend-partition-sizes-for-my-dual-boot-configuration-1tb-big-ntfs-p) (there were more), setting a bigger space aside for my home partition. I now tried to install matlab with all its complements in the suggested directory in /usr/local but run out of space. I looked online and matlab with the whole complements takes about 20GB so that may make sense.

What did I do wrong?

1. Should have put more space for the root partition, guidelines were wrong
2. The recommended size made sense, Matlab+all packages is just unexpectedly big.
3. I should not install some programs in /usr/local, but somewhere else.
4. Something else

In any case, what's the best way to proceed? I currently have installed matlab+complements in home, where I have plenty of space (but in Hard Disk, not SSD).

Comment: I'd say #1 and #2.

Comment: Aren't #1 and #2 contradictory? Either the guidelines were right (#2) or they were not (#1)

Comment: ok... then "Should have put more space for the root partition" AND "Matlab+all packages is just unexpectedly big".

Comment: I just create one big btrfs partition and subdivide it using subvolumes that can be mounted or backed up separately. In this case all free space is shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say the recommended size still makes sense, though I tend to use bigger partition sizes because we have so much space available nowadays, even on SSD. Currently, I have a 45 GiB root on one machine, and 60 GiB on another machine.

Even though I use bigger partitions, in practical use, with a comfortable selection of software, I use much less than 25 GiB: about 6 GiB for the software, and a couple of GiB in `/var`. The rest is in separate partitions (`/home` and data).

So 25 GiB is not an incorrect advice. I would only worry about modern games (which tend to use GiB like it's free). And now that I've read your question, Matlab too.